# How much free storage for videos in Google Photos Backup?

Tags: google-photos

How much space for videos is included in free Google Photos Backup for Mac?

Answer (score 2):

Google Photos use Google Drive Storage. At this time it has 15 GB for free. It's worth to say that ...

> You can choose between 2 storage sizes to back up your photos and
> videos to your Google Photos library.
>
> ### High quality
>
> - Unlimited free storage
> - Regular cameras: Recommended for phones or point-and-shoot cameras that are        16 megapixels (MP) or less.
> - Uses: Good for typical printing and sharing.
> - Size: Save high-quality photos and videos while reducing size.
>
> ### Original
>
> - Limited free storage: Uses your Google Account's 15 GB of free storage. [Check my storage](https://www.google.com/settings/storage).
> - DSLR cameras: Recommended if you take photos with a DSLR camera and want to maintain the exact original quality.
> - Uses: Recommended for printing large banners or to store your original files.
> - Size: Store your photos and videos exactly as you captured them.

**References**
[Choose a storage size - Google Photos Help](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6220791?hl=en)